# OOM in nuxtjs, these could cause the memory leakage?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, oom

Recently, I have been debugging legacy code. One of our services was having an OOM problem. After server load testing, I thought two of things could cause the problem. One is the methods that are defined from the component and the other is the socket method that doesn't have disconnection in created method.

In the `index.vue`

```
const definedOutOfComponent () => {
   // requestData
}

export default {

  asyncData() { 
    definedOutOfComponent();
  }

  created() {
    this.setSocket();
  }

  setSocket() {
    
    // setSocket method doesn't have disconnection.
    
  }

}
```

Here is the reason why I thought these two things cause the problem. First, method like definedOutOfComponent is created every access and there is no disconnect on `setSocket()` method.

But, I'm newer to NuxtJs. So, I need some help from advanced developer's opinion. Do you think it could have effect on memory leak?

Comment: Also, in the Nuxtjs docs, created method is the Vue's lifecycle method. But, Why it runs in server load tests?